# ASP.NET MVC : binding to model within a loop

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, model-binding

I'm pretty new to ASP.NET MVC, and I'm trying to figure out if I am able to bind data to my model property from within a loop.

Can I bind it maybe in the `onClick` event?

At the moment `chosenTime` is 1/01/0001 12:00:00 AM.

My code for the view is as follows:

```
@model ResSProject.Models.Sittings.SittingTimesVM

<div class="d-flex justify-content-center">

    <div>@Model.RestaurantName</div>
    <div class="px-5">@Model.Date.ToString("dd-MMMM-yyyy")</div>
    <div>@Model.NumberOfGuests</div>
</div>
<form method="post" asp-action="Reservation">
    @{TimeSpan T1 = new TimeSpan(0, 15, 0);
     
        for (var increase = Model.SittingsStart.Subtract(T1); increase < Model.SittingsEnd;)
        {
            increase = increase.AddMinutes(15);

            <input class="btn btn-primary w-50 mx-auto mt-3 " type="button"  asp-for="ChosenTime" value="@increase.ToString("HH:mm tt")" />
        }
    }

    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />

    <input type="hidden" asp-for=NumberOfGuests />
    <input type="hidden" asp-for=Date />
    <input type="hidden" asp-for=RestaurantName />
    <input type="hidden" asp-for=RestaurantId />
    <input type="hidden" asp-for=SittingsStart />
    <input type="hidden" asp-for=SittingsEnd />
</form>
```

My view model class is:

```
using ResSProject.Data;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace ResSProject.Models.Sittings
{
    public class SittingTimesVM
    {
        public DateTime Date { get; set; }
        public int RestaurantId { get; set; }
        public string RestaurantName { get; set; }
        public int NumberOfGuests { get; set; } 
        public DateTime ChosenTime { get; set; }
        public DateTime SittingsStart { get; set; }
        public DateTime SittingsEnd { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi @JUJU, 1. what do you mean for `Can I bind it maybe in the onClick event?` and I never see such related code from what you shared. 2. What do you want to bind the data to do? Bind it to display the value in the page or bind it to post to the backend?   Pls share more details with us.

Comment: Besides, your input for `ChosenTime` is a button, it cannot be post the backend by simple form submit. Maybe your onclick event is prepared for this input? But in foreach loop, it may contain multiple inputs for this  `ChosenTime` , although we can use js to get the data, but your model is type of DateTime, multiple datetime data cannot bind to the property.

Comment: Or you mean you click one of the inputs, and will pass this clicked value to backend and bind it to the model?

Comment: Or you mean you click one of the inputs, and will pass this clicked value to backend and bind it to the model? 
yes, thats what im trying to achieve, but I'm not sure if this is the best way to go about it, or how to do it.

Comment: Hi @JUJU, if so, you can check my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Button type element cannot be passed to backend. I think you need set a hidden input and use js to set the chosen time.

Besides, the value of the inputs are **just time without date**(v`alue="@increase.ToString("HH:mm tt")"`). When you post the value, it will bind time with **current date** to the property `ChosenTime`. If the `SittingsStart` and `SittingsEnd` are not the same date with current now, the chosen time will be not correct.

Whole working demo:

```
@model SittingTimesVM

<div class="d-flex justify-content-center">

    <div>@Model.RestaurantName</div>
    <div class="px-5">@Model.Date.ToString("dd-MMMM-yyyy")</div>
    <div>@Model.NumberOfGuests</div>
</div>
<form method="post" asp-action="Reservation">
    @{TimeSpan T1 = new TimeSpan(0, 15, 0);
     
        for (var increase = Model.SittingsStart.Subtract(T1); increase < Model.SittingsEnd;)
        {
            increase = increase.AddMinutes(15);

            <input class="btn btn-primary w-50 mx-auto mt-3 " type="button" asp-for="ChosenTime"
                 onclick="GetValue(this)"  value="@increase.ToString("dd-MMMM-yyy HH:mm tt")" />
                                       
        }
    }
    <input asp-for="ChosenTime" type="hidden"/>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />

    <input type="hidden" asp-for=NumberOfGuests />
    <input type="hidden" asp-for=Date />
    <input type="hidden" asp-for=RestaurantName />
    <input type="hidden" asp-for=RestaurantId />
    <input type="hidden" asp-for=SittingsStart />
    <input type="hidden" asp-for=SittingsEnd />
</form>
@section Scripts
{
    <script>
        function GetValue(e)
        {    
            $('input:hidden[name=ChosenTime]').val($(e).val())
        }
    </script>
}
```

Backend:

```
[HttpPost]
public void Reservation(SittingTimesVM model)
{
   //do your stuff...
}
```

---

**Another way** I better suggest is to combine `<input>` elements to one `<select>` element, and it is no need add any onclick event to set value. It can bind to model property successfully upon you set `asp-for="ChosenTime"` for the `<select>` element.

```
@{
    TimeSpan T1 = new TimeSpan(0, 15, 0);
    <select  type="button" asp-for="ChosenTime">
        @for (var increase = Model.SittingsStart.Subtract(T1); increase < Model.SittingsEnd;)
        {
            increase = increase.AddMinutes(15);
            <option value="@increase.ToString("dd-MMMM-yyy HH:mm tt")">@increase.ToString("HH:mm tt")</option>                                       
        }
    </select>        
}
```